# Azure Hybrid Benefit-Self-Installed SQL Server on Azure VM

Tags: azure, license, virtualisation

The Microsoft documentation says if you self-install SQL Server on Azure VM, you need to manually register with the SQL IaaS Agent Extension and activate Azure Hybrid Benefit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/licensing-model-azure-hybrid-benefit-ahb-change?view=azuresql-vm&tabs=azure-portal

## Scenario

What happens if one installs SQL Server Enterprise Edition and omits the step to register the SQL IaaS Agent Extension and activate Azure Hybrid Benefit?

Does this mean that only compute charges will be applied and that SQL licenses charges will be excluded ?

OR

Does Microsoft have some way of detecting that SQL Server has been self-installed thereby causing the licensing model to default to Pay as you go (PAYG) i.e. you pay for both Compute + SQL Licenses?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for Microsoft support. My guess is the answer isn't something favorable, e.g. the wrong licensing model or just straight up being out of compliance. Unfortunately licensing questions are off-topic here though, so reaching out to Microsoft would be your best bet.

Comment: Thank You J.D for the feedback